# add shading to asp.net imagemap.hotspot

Tags: asp.net, image

I am trying to add shading or some type of coloring to hotspots within an asp imagemap control.

The overall scope is we have a map overlay and within each map we have n number of hotspots. However while the hotspots are there it is not to readily visible to the end user unless they just hunt over the image until the cursor changes.

I need some way of letting the end user know there is a click-able hotspot on this section of the map.